# Email output adding line breaks when inserting variables into email body using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have an email that's being automatically generated and filling the body with results from a query. It is outputting query result items on separate lines.

The Results appear like:

> LOB:
>
> Comments

But Should Appear as:

> LOB: Comments

```
strQryResults = strQryResults & "<li><span style='color:#000000;font-family:arial;'>" & ![LOB] & ": " & ![Comments] & "</Span>" & vbCrLf
.MoveNext
```

How can I remove these line breaks?

When I do Left(![Comments], 4) I  see:

```
<div
```

This is what's creating the new line, but what's creating the

```
<div>
```

Comment: what is the field type of `![Comments]`? Try `Trim(![Comments])`? or set `![Comments]` to a separate variable and then concatenate the final string together.

Comment: [Comments] is a "Long Text" field type. I attempted to concatenate them together and to trim, and the items were still formatting in the original (incorrect) way.

Comment: So the "<div" is embedded in your [Comments] column. This suggests to me that this field has been configured in MS Access as "Rich Text", allowing the user to apply formatting such as bold text or different font sizes. Internally, this "Rich Text" is stored as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Updated to show answer/workaround:

In order to remove the unnecessary div tags, I replaced ![Comments] with:

```
Mid(![Comments], 6, Len(![Comments]) - 5)
```